# Photon Server connecting Demo perform error on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, server, photon

> Hello, World.

I am working on Photon Server.
Try to run a demo file after download SDK from Photon. Btw some accidents.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/demo.android.loadBalancing-GIL4HGl5AqJzcC3EdKzdFg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/demo.android.loadBalancing-GIL4HGl5AqJzcC3EdKzdFg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libdemoLoadBalancing.so"
```

I thought this error was happened by .so find not find. But the Photon support said that is wrong. He said to me that I have to include .a file, not .so as a static library.

Below is my Android.mk file.

```
# Generated by VisualGDB

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
PHOTON_SDK_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../..

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := demoLoadBalancing
#VisualGDBAndroid: AutoUpdateSourcesInNextLine
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../src/NetworkLogic.cpp AndroidNetworkLogic.cpp main.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(PHOTON_SDK_ROOT) ../inc/ ../../shared/inc
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wall -DEG_DEBUGGER -D__STDINT_LIMITS -D_EG_ANDROID_PLATFORM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := loadbalancing-cpp-static-prebuilt photon-cpp-static-prebuilt common-cpp-static-prebuilt
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path, $(PHOTON_SDK_ROOT)/LoadBalancing-cpp/lib)

$(call import-module,loadbalancing-cpp-prebuilt)
```

It's trying to connect the Photon server on Android studio without PUN - Unity SDK Only JAVA/Kotlin.
The source code in
https://github.com/Baymax-bibi/Android-photon-server-working.git

If someone has experience in Photon Server connect, Please share for a coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to Solve my posted Question and met Photon Support. They said to me below.

> Those errors indicate an incompatibility between the stdlib version
> that your app links against and the one that the Photon libs link
> against.
>
> The SDK provides libs that have been built against the gcc version of
> the stdlib (libstdc++) and libs that have been built against the clang
> version of the stdlib (libc++). The former ones are used on default
> and the lattter ones have an additional 'libc++' postfix in their
> filenames.
>
> It looks like your app links against the clang version of the stdlib
> and against those builds of Photon libs that link against the gcc
> version of the stdlib.
>
> However your app and all 3rd party libs that your apps link to must
> agreed on using the same version of the stdlib as those 2 incompatible
> versions can't be mixed with each other.
>
> Please see
> https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/42718/#Comment_42718
> for instructions on how to link against the libc++ variants of the
> Photon libs.
>
> Doing so should fix your errors.

Looks like works for me... )

Comment: If this post helps anyone, please share your experience and feeling on this.

Comment: https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/52007#Comment_52007